# How do I eliminate the whitespace between my title bar and the top of my page in my rails website

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, web, devise, sass

[image: The problem]

So I'm working on a rails website and I'm having a little design problem. It seems that this code for the devise gem is causing whitespace to appear between the titlebar and the top of the page.

```
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

Adding an if statement to the these classes gets rid of the problem in the landing page but it still persists in other pages.

```
<% if !(controller_name == "home" && action_name == "index") %>
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
<% end %>
```

If anyone knows a workaround to this problem I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Edit 1: I'm using Foundation framework

Comment: Please post the computed CSS for .notice and .alert.  I have a feeling there are margins on the "p" elements.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just override the CSS style that's causing the problem?

Comment: So I forgot to mention that I'm using Foundation I don't know what css they use for their title bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this if statement:

```
<% unless notice.nil? %>
   <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
<% unless alert.nil? %>
   <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
<% end %>
```